# Relating Statistics to Grades (No number)

Tags: self-study, interpretation

I have the following table and need to answer the following questions. The first question does not appear to me to have enough information.

```
Name    Age MATH    ENGLISH RESIDENCE
Tammy   16  C   A   CAMPUS
Peter   16  B   A   CAMPUS
Tom     17  C   A   CAMPUS
Lynn    18  A   A   CAMPUS
Michael 20  A   A   CAMPUS
Steven  21  B   A   CAMPUS
Sam     22  B   B   CAMPUS
Mary    25  A   C   CAMPUS
Bob     17  C   A   HOME
Mindy   17  A   A   HOME
John    18  A   A   HOME
Dan     18  C   A   HOME
Lily    22  B   B   HOME
Sue     23  A   B   HOME
Corey   24  B   B   HOME
```

1. What conclusion can you make about the summer classes in English and Math?
2. Do older students do better in math?
3. Are females better than males in math?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Chuck. Note that homework problems get special treatment here--we provide hints to help you work through the problem, but don't provide answers for you (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) & [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about)). To help you better, can you say what you've tried thus far, & where you're stuck?

Comment: +1 This is a brilliant set of questions in the way it touches on some key issues of data interpretation and analysis that are rarely discussed. The first is great precisely because it compels the question asked here; namely, "is there enough information?"  I especially appreciate #3, because it invites us to use these data in an invalid, non-reproducible, yet entirely natural way: namely, by *assuming* we can infer gender from name.  (I know of both males and females named "Lynn," "Sam," and "Corey.")

Comment: You should make a histogram of the two courses and see what it looks like then.